# Free Path Probability Distribution for an Ideal Gas

Tags: statistical-mechanics, mean-free-path

Suppose we have a gas with collisions. The [mean free path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_free_path), $l$, is the average distance a particle travels before colliding with another particle. This is the average, but what is the *probability distribution* of collisions? It cannot be a Gaussian, because there can be no collisions with $x<0.$ It also cannot be a Poisson distribution, because the distance traveled, $x$, is a real number.

The answer to this question will clearly depend on the nature of interactions between the particles, the (effective) radius of the particles, etc. But I have not found any resource which answers this question from a simple starting point.

Comment: wiki? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_free_path

$d\mathcal{P}(x) = \frac{1}{\ell} e^{-x/\ell} dx$

Comment: @warlock I do not see a probability distribution on the wiki for the cases I am interested in

Comment: so what is wrong with the distribution I quoted?